# angular text in utf8 from json file

Tags: angularjs, utf-8, http-headers

i call a service angular json file. In the file there some chars "ùàò".
When i print in template the chars, they are ?

### these are header call

Access-Control-Allow-Head...
Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...
GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...
*
Connection
Keep-Alive
Content-Length
394
Content-Type
application/json; **charset=UTF-8**
Date
Thu, 19 Nov 2015 12:09:13 GMT
Keep-Alive
timeout=5, max=100
Server
Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.5.8
X-Powered-By
PHP/5.5.8

If i try to set in angular the $httpProvider, any change

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"]="application/json; charset=UTF-8";
```

the call header and response header are all in utf8, why FF or Chrome not show correctly?

Comment: Try this in the <head> tag: `<meta charset='utf-8'>`

Comment: i know,but it's already present and don't work
index.html==><head><meta charset="utf-8">
also the browser is set to "unicode"

Comment: Are you sure your source file is encoded in UTF-8? Also make sure your Angular page is in UTF-8 as well (Not just the header, but actually set in the editor)